# Stock return - Regression with multiple dummies

Tags: regression, categorical-data, regression-coefficients, finance

I have a case where I want to test if a corporate credit rating change by Moody's affects the company/security that experience the event. I also want to test if the effect is more or less extreme after a specific financial regulation. Thus far I have set it up like this (where change is 1 when there is a credit rating change, regulation is 1 after the financial regulation and DID is the difference in differences):

```
| company_ID | stock_return | market_return | dummy_change | dummy_regulation | dummy_DID |
|-----------:|-------------:|--------------:|-------------:|-----------------:|----------:|
|          1 |        0.041 |         0.027 |            1 |                0 |         0 |
|          1 |       -0.027 |         0.012 |            0 |                0 |         0 |
|            |          ... |           ... |          ... |              ... |       ... |
|         34 |       -0.021 |         0.011 |            1 |                1 |         1 |
|         34 |        0.017 |        -0.012 |            0 |                1 |         0 |
```

And then regressed it:

$$R_{t}=\alpha _{} + \beta _{}R_{mt} + \gamma _{}D_{change} + \delta _{}D_{regulation} +  \lambda _{}D_{DID} + u_{t} $$

where $\beta$ is the exposure to the market (around 1 if every stock is included), and $\gamma$, $\delta$ and $\lambda$ are the return associated with changes in credit rating, financial regulation and the difference between a change before and after the financial regulation.

This was my thought. However, I'm not sure if this method is either meaningful or appropriate. Can we state that a significant value of say $\lambda$, is proof that there is a difference before and after regulation?

Comment: Please use proper english grammar & capitalization.

Comment: At the very least people include Fama's 4 factors instead of just the "market return". I'd run this through corp fin people, they have their typical set ups for this kind of regression equation. Personally, I think none of this makes a sense, but if you make it look like one of corp fin's standard equations, they'll swallow it.

Comment: Thank you, @Aksakal. I have debated using Fama's three factor (four), and I will definitely implement them now. Would you care to elaborate on why it doesn't make sense? I'm not a statistician so if it's flawed in terms of statistics I would be interested in your thoughts about it.

Comment: You're probably trying to see whether the ratings downgrade has a new information that impacts the stock price. Does this mean that the ratings agency has access to some information that is not already known to investors? Or that the information is in their processing of public data? They'r not supposed to get insider info. So the ratings change could be a reaction to earnings release or something else released publically, which already impacted the returns. So it will look like ratings change caused the shock while in fact it was earnings release shocking both the price and the rating.

Comment: Also, the ratings change may have very different effect depending on what was the rating exactly. AAA down is not the same as B down a notch. Some stocks are included in SPX, such as AAPL and very liquid. There are stocks which are not in the indices but are traded well, then you have stocks traded very rarely. Then you have different industries such as financials vs. commodities, they have different leverage ratios. You're looking at the ratings of the debt, leverage matters etc. You have to "control" for all of this nonlinearity and confounding if you want something that makes a sense at all

Comment: Thank you, @Aksakal! Well, rating agencies actually have access to confidential information provided by the firms that are rated. They do however, not disclose that information in their announcement. I would guess they use that information in their analysis but i can't know for certain. And yes, the correlation/causation problem is absolutely present as a lot of rating changes come as a direct consequence of another event such as an earnings announcement.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. The bottom line is that there is more than one way to specify a model and unless you have a PhD committee scrutinizing your work, you have a lot of leeway to motivate a wide range of approaches.

You are right to control for market returns but what about additional control variables for sector or industry? This would be logical in that regulatory changes can have widely differing impacts by industry. It would also offer the option to consider a multi-level approach to modeling since stocks (entities) are nested within industry.

Rating changes can be both up and down, correct? I question using a single 0,1 dummy variable to capture these changes. A better approach would be to use effect size coding where -1 is a downgrade, zero is no change and +1 is an upgrade. However, both of these approaches to coding won't capture differential effects as a function of the *level* of the rating. In other words, if you plugged in the actual rating grade (e.g., Aaa, Ba1, etc.) and tracked the rating changes this way, your model would be sensitized to the level of the rating and, therefore, more informative.

Similarly, regulatory changes are usually not just of a single type and using one 0,1 dummy variable to capture them will collapse any nuances in the regulatory changes into a single effect that will not be further decomposable. You might consider the possibility of integrating additional classifications to the regulatory change variable.

The beauty of the pooled time-series model you've proposed is its simplicity and flexibility. Regrettably, market returns are also known to be sensitive to autocorrelation, periodicities, trends and seasonalities of various types such as day of week, week and month of year, etc., some of which can only be assumed away under pooling. If you have enough data points, you can control for these issues as well, further refining your estimates. This would necessitate shifting the functional form from the pooled, MNL approach you're leveraging now to a more HAC (white noise residual) ARIMA or GARCH-type model where lags, MVAs and/or variance regimes can be integrated, investigated and controlled for.

I'm confused by your DID factor. How are you specifying it? Would an interaction between the rating grade and regulatory changes be a simpler, more efficient and informative approach?

Finally, does the temporal range of your returns include 2008 crash days where returns might be extreme valued? If so, you might want to consider using quantile regression for more robust estimation.

Anyway, those are a few quick thoughts.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you. I have debated controlling for different sectors/industries and using the suggested model in the comment above (Fama). When it comes to ratings in terms of up/down my thought was to look at them seperately. I probably should have explained the DID factor better but it is defined as DID = change*regulation. That is what you meant, right? And if significant it could indicate that changes before/after regulation are different (It's one regulation at the same point in time for all stocks).

Comment: Yes, your DID appears to be the same as my interaction. You still might consider a control factor for the actual rating grade versus separate dummies for the direction of the change.

Comment: Actually, while Akasakal's points are generally informative, a rating change can act as an exogenous shock over and above the information already absorbed in any earnings surprises, etc. The reason for this is that many financial obligations are directly tied to the maintenance of debt ratings and a downgrade can trigger a cascade of bad news for a company that can result in things like interest rate increases not to mention that a slip in level from investment to junk grade can trigger another asymmetric shift in perceptions.